# How to call doctrine.entitymanager.orm_default in zf2 plugin

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

I wanna use my entities inside my custom plugin. So, I am doing in that order:

1) Declared my plugin in Module\src\Plugin\Plugin.php

```
  namespace Application\Plugin;

  use Zend\Mvc\Controller\Plugin\AbstractPlugin;
  use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
  use User\Entity\UserProfile;
  use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager;

  class AuthenticationPlugin extends AbstractPlugin {
       protected $entityManager;
       protected $serviceManager;

  public function setServiceManager(ServiceManager $locator) {
       $this->serviceManager = $locator;
  }

  public function getServiceManager() {
       return $this->serviceManager;
  }

  public function getEntityManager() {
       $userEntityFactory = new \Application\Factory\UserEntityFactory();

       $this->entityManager = $userEntityFactory->createService($this->getServiceManager());

       return $this->entityManager;
  }

  public function someAction($user_email) {
       $user = $this->getEntityManager()->getRepository('User\Entity\User')->findBy(array('email'=>$user_email));
  }
}
```

2) Created my factory:

```
 namespace User\Factory;

 use Zend\ServiceManager\FactoryInterface;
 use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorInterface;

 class UserEntityFactory implements FactoryInterface {

     public function createService(ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator) {
        return $serviceLocator->get('doctrine.entitymanager.orm_default');
     }    
 }
```

3) Defines it in module.config.php:

```
'service_manager' => array(
    'factories' => array(
        'UserEntityFactory' => 'Application\Factory\UserEntityFactory',
    ),
),
'controller_plugins' => array(
    'invokables' => array(
        'AuthenticationPlugin' => 'Application\Plugin\AuthenticationPlugin',
    )
),
```

4) Sending ServiceLocator to my plugin in Module.php:

```
public function getServiceConfig() {
        return array(
            'factories' => array(
                'AuthenticationPlugin' => function($sm) {
                    $locator = $sm->getServiceLocator();
                    $instance = new \Application\Plugin\AuthenticationPlugin();
                    $instance->setServiceManager($locator);

                    return $instance;
                },
            ),
        );
    }
```

5) ...and calling it in onBootstrap:

```
$em->attach('ZfcUser\Service\User', 'register', function($e) {

       $user = $e->getParam('user');  // User account object
       $authenticationPlugin = new AuthenticationPlugin();
       $authenticationPlugin->someAction($user->getEmail());
   });
```

But I received the error that $locator in plugin is null... I'm confused and I am sure that I'm doing something wrong... or all. I would be happy if somebody will share experiences or will show the order of actions. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to inject the entire service manager object into your plugin class.

You only need to inject the User\Entity\User repository object, this appears to be the only dependancy required in your plugin class.

You should pass this into the constructor of your plugin class via your factory :

```
public function getServiceConfig() {
        return array(
            'factories' => array(
                'AuthenticationPlugin' => function($sm) {
                    return new \Application\Plugin\AuthenticationPlugin($sm->get('doctrine.entitymanager.orm_default')->getRepository('User\Entity\User'));
                },
            ),
        );
    }
```

in your plugin class:

```
    class AuthenticationPlugin extends AbstractPlugin {

    private $userRepository;

    public function __construct(\User\Entity\User $userRepository){

        $this->userRepository=$userRepository;

    }

    public function someAction($user_email) {
       $user = $this->userRepository->findBy(array('email'=>$user_email));
    }
                                                      }
```

As you are configuring the plugin via the module.php you don't need to also declare the plugin as an invokable in your config file. So remove the following line from your module.config.php

```
'AuthenticationPlugin' => 'Application\Plugin\AuthenticationPlugin'
```

As a side note, there are various pros and cons between declaring your services/plugins in either the module.php or the module.config file. This though wasn't the question so I won't go into detail here.

Comment: Thanks, but when I'm trying to pass User\Entity\User to plugin constructor I've got the error: Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to AuthenticationPlugin::__construct() must be an instance of User\Entity\User, none given, called in /module/Application/Module.php on line 37 and defined in /module/Application/src/Application/Plugin/AuthenticationPlugin.php. In my Controller all works fine, but in plugin is not. I've tried to pass other class to plugin construct and I've got same error but now instead of User\Entity\User it is other class...

Comment: can you paste your Module.php file here please.

Comment: ok I see the problem you have also declared the plugin as an invokable so it is being called twice, once via your module bootstrap file and also via the  config declaration. The solution now is to remove one. As you have correctly configured the Module.php you can simply remove the declaration from the config file, I'll update the answer above to reflect this.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I understood and solved this problem. The error was that I was working wrong with the events in onBootstrap and I incorrectly called my plugin.